# Sorting Entire GridView with Custom Page Control

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server-2008, gridview

In my GridView I turned paging off as I created a custom paging control. I have a SQL stored procedure where I pass in the page numbers to return as parameters. The problem I now have is that sorting no longer works other than for the current records returned which is 1000. When I turn on sorting, the current set of 1000 records are sorted, not the entire record set. I'm sure thats because my stored procedure is only returning 1000 records as well. The only way I can think to accomplish what I'm looking to do is pass in all the column names as case statements and sort based on them as additional parameters. There must be a better way though than this. Any thoughts?

This is what I'm currently doing and works fine without sorting. @StartRow and @EndRow are always based on page number passed where @StartRow equals page number * 1000 (1000 rows per page returned).

```
@StartRow INT,
@EndRow INT
AS

SELECT * FROM
    (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY EmployeeID) AS Row,
        HR.EmployeeID, HR.FirstName, HR.LastName,
        ISNULL(Locations.City,'') + ', ' + ISNULL(Locations.State,'') as LocationName
    FROM HR
        INNER JOIN Locations ON HR.LocationID = Locations.LocationID
    ) AS X
GROUP BY X.Row, X.EmployeeID, X.FirstName, X.LastName
HAVING X.Row BETWEEN @StartRow AND @EndRow
ORDER BY X.Row
```

This is the only way I can think to accomplish sorting while using a custom paging control like I have. Though I'm thinking there is a much better way that just isn't coming to mind.

```
@StartRow INT,
@EndRow INT,
@Sort nvarchar(25)
AS

CREATE TABLE #Temp1
(
            EmployeeID nvarchar(25),
            FirstName nvarchar(25),
            LastName nvarchar(25),
            LocationName nvarchar(25)
)

INSERT INTO #Temp1
SELECT * FROM
    (
    SELECT 
        HR.EmployeeID, HR.FirstName, HR.LastName,
        ISNULL(Locations.City,'') + ', ' + ISNULL(Locations.State,'') as LocationName
    FROM HR
        INNER JOIN Locations ON HR.LocationID = Locations.LocationID
    ) AS X
GROUP BY X.EmployeeID, X.FirstName, X.LastName, X.LocationName

SELECT * FROM
    (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 
                                CASE 
                                    WHEN @Sort = 'EmployeeID' THEN #Temp1.EmployeeID 
                                    WHEN @Sort = 'FirstName' THEN #Temp1.FirstName
                                    WHEN @Sort = 'LastName' THEN #Temp1.LastName
                                    WHEN @Sort = 'LocationName' THEN #Temp1.LocationName
                                    ELSE #Temp1.EmployeeID
                                END 
    ) AS Row, *
    FROM #Temp1 
    ) AS X
WHERE X.Row BETWEEN @StartRow AND @EndRow

drop table #Temp1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could build a string that has your sql statement and then execute that string...

```
SET @SqlString = N'SELECT... ORDER BY ' + @Sort
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString
```

You will need to really constrain that @Sort string so you are not vulnerable to sql injection, but if you make sure that string is sanitized, then this should be ok.

Also, and for the same reason (to prevent sql injection) you will want to either treat the startrow and endrow as parameters, or again, sanitize them and then insert them into SqlString as literals.

Comment: I should mention that I have several hundred reports on this site and have stored procedures created for each of them. Going the route that you suggest above wouldn't work very well with that in mind.

Comment: I don't understand why not.  In your last code snippet, in your stored procedure, you would just replace the last select statement with a built sql string that you then execute with sp_executesql.  It would be simpler than adding that case statement to each of the stored procedures, wouldn't it?